# If $L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and if $L=HK$ (where $H$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is any subgroup), then must $K$ also be normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think the answer is yes, but I just want to ask in case I'm missing something...

We know that $aKH=KHa$ for all a in G. But we also know that $aH = Ha$, so $KHa = KaH$.

So $aKH = KaH \implies aK=Ka$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Take G=L=H to be nonabelian of order 6, and K of order 2.

Notice that aKH = aKG = G, and that KaH = KaG = G, so aKH = KaH only tells you G = G, nothing about K or a. You cannot generally cancel subsets.

Comment: Your counter-example still works, and is much neater (or rather, less vacuous-seeming), if you take $H$ to be cyclic of order three, with $G$, $L$ and $K$ as before. (This is neater because you are not just using $K\leq K\cap H$, as $K\cap H=\langle 1\rangle$ here. Keyword(s): [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).)

Comment: It is important to answer the question being asked. I chose H=G to emphasize the error being made: canceling subsets. If he had not made that error but thought that groups cannot factor as HK, then H order 3 would be a better example, but in this case it obscurs the problem.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks a lot. So if $G \not= L \not=H$, is my proof correct...or is there still a problem?

Comment: No, your proof is completely wrong and the result is completely false.

Comment: @Artus: That is the point my comment is making - *even if* $L\neq H$ then the proof doesn't hold. there is no way of changing the conditions to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

So $aKH=KaH  \ then  K^{-1}a^{-1}Ka\in H$\ 
It seems this way cannot be Ok. you can use this way :
$K=H^{-1}L$ is normal subgroup ,because $H\  L$ are both normal .

Comment: It is not correct that K has the form you claim.

Comment: Oh,sorry. 
$aK\subset L,for\ a\in H$
then $K\subset a^{-1}L\subset H^{-1}L$.we can proof $ H^{-1}L$ is normal subgroup.
and $K$ is subgroup of $H^{-1}L $. and the subgroup of normal subgroup is also normal .
Thus ,this proposition was certified.

Comment: $H^{-1} = H$ as $H$ is a subgroup. A normal subgroup of a normal subgroup need not be normal in the larger group.